# A laptop has got two graphic cards (Nvidia and Intel); how can I check which graphic card is using a particular application?

Tags: windows, graphics-card

I'm checking on a particular Windows high-end laptop (Zbook) in which two graphic cards are installed, which one is used by the application I launched; what's the right way to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Windows 10 and have any version from the last few years you can use Task Manager.

On the Processes tab you see

[image]

And you can find out which GPU is which on the Performance tab

[image]

Comment: So easy, great and THANK YOU!